# how to place variables from app/config.yml in a bundles routing.yml?

Tags: symfony, routes

I'd like to make some routes dynamic depending on the app -> config.yml file.

In the app's config.yml file i'd like to place:

```
i7_core_admin:
    backend_route_basename: "backend123"
```

in my bundles routing.yml i tried

```
pattern:  /%i7_core_admin.backend_route_basename%/{name}
```

But it seams that the %var% variables in routing.yml can only be placed in parameters.yml which i'd like to avoid. I'd like to place them in config.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define it as

```
parameters:
    i7_core_admin:
        backend_route_basename: "backend123"
```

All parameters must be defined under `parameters` section. And only then it will be parsed with '%...%' pattern. Your `parameters.yml` also have `parameters` section. But you can define it anywhere in includable config files.